# Can't fetch data from database table.... 500 error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried a ton of different versions of this code, from tons of different websites. I am entirely confused why this isn't working. Even copy and pasted code wont work. I am fairly new to PHP and MySQL, but have done a decent amount of HTML, CSS, and JS so I am not super new to code in general, but I am still a beginner

Here is what I have. I am trying to fetch data from a database to compare it to user entered data from the last page (essentially a login thing). I haven't even gotten to the comparison part yet because I can't fetch information, all I am getting is a 500 error code in chrome's debug window. I am completely clueless on this because everything I have read says this should be completely fine.

I'm completely worn out from this, it's been frustrating me to no end. Hopefully someone here can help. For the record, it connects just fine, its the minute I try to use the $sql variable that everything falls apart. I'm doing this on Godaddy hosting, if that means anything.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "joemama198";
$pass = "Password";
$dbname = "EmployeeTimesheet";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_conect($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqi_connect_error();
}

$sql = 'SELECT Name FROM Employee List'; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo "Name: " . $row["Name"]. "<br>";
        }
     } else {
        echo "0 results";
     }
     mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

Comment: Can you show error message?

Comment: What is your database name as you are using 2 names after FROM in `$sql`

Comment: My database is EmployeeTimesheet. The table inside that database that I am trying to access is EmployeeList

Comment: Error message is 500 (internal server error)

Answer (score 1):

There be trouble here:

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_conect($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqi_connect_error();
}
```

There are three problems here:

1. `mysqli_conect()` instead of `mysqli_connect()` (note the double `n` in `connect`)
2. `mysqli_connect_errno` should be a function: `mysqli_connect_errno()`
3. `mysqi_connect_error()` instead of `mysqli_connect_error()` (note the `l` in `mysqli`)

The reason you're getting a 500 error is that you do not have debugging enabled. Please add the following to the very top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

That should prevent a not-so-useful 500 error from appearing, and should instead show the actual ***reason*** for any other errors.

There **might** be a problem here:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

If the query fails, `$result` will be `false` and you will get an error on the `mysqli_num_rows()` call. You should add a check between there:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
    die('Query failed because: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I finally got my code to work. Also that debug thing was wonderful, the 500 error was super unhelpful.

I copied and pasted that code with all the spelling errors. I will have to spellcheck more often.

This has been driving me insane, thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help :-) Keep in mind for next time that when your browser is showing a 500 error, your server logs should contain the actual error. No idea where GoDaddy stores those though, or if they're even available at all there.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your database table in your select statement has a space in it. If that is intended try:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Name FROM `Employee List`';
```

Comment: Fixed that, as well as changed my database name in phpMyAdmin. still nothing unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

i think you left blank space in your query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT Name FROM Employee List';
```

change to

```
$sql = "SELECT `Name` FROM `EmployeeList`";
```

Comment: Upvoted, because this was a valid point and could have caused a 500 error since the query was assumed to be successful. The original query was an implicit alias (the same as `SELECT \`Name\` FROM \`Employee\` AS \`List\``), which would have failed if there is no table called "Employee".

Comment: Oh okay @rickdenhaan understood.